# How to return literals from flex to yacc?

Tags: grammar, yacc, lexical-analysis

In my yacc file I have things like the following:

```
var_declaration : type_specifier ID ';'
                | type_specifier ID '[' NUM ']' ';' ;

type_specifier : INT | VOID ;
```

ID, NUM, INT, and VOID are tokens that get returned from flex, so yacc has no problems recognizing them.  The problem is that in the above there are things like '[' and ';'.  When these are recognized by flex, what should be returned to yacc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return the characters themselves. Tokens are guaranteed not to conflict with ASCII characters:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Token-Decl.html

> Bison will automatically select codes
>   that don't conflict with each other or
>   with ASCII characters.

So in your flex file,

```
[\[\];]     { return yytext[0]; }
```

is OK.

Comment: It is a rule which matches any one of the three characters '[', ']', or ';'.

Comment: Oops, accidentally clicked the down arrow.  If you edit your answer it will allow me to change it and I'll click the up arrow.

I also need to match other things like () and {}.  Is there something similar for those?

Comment: Sure, use [{}] to match { or }, etc. The [ ] is a character class and this is a regular expression which matches anything inside it.